# Implicit redefinition of parameters

Tags: system-verilog

The `#` token sometimes appears before the parameter list in a Verilog module. This is said to indicate implicit redefinition of parameters. In [this](http://www.gitam.edu/eresource/comp/prnr/vhdl/instances.htm) example `(2)` follows the `#` token with no explanation given:

```
  //implicit parameter redefine
  dff #(2) u4 (q[3], , d[3], clock);
```

The explanation [here](http://www.eda.org/sv-bc/hm/att-3223/clause06_data_declarations.pdf) makes more sense, where the redefined values follow the `#` token:

```
 Implicit in-line parameter redefinition (e.g. foo #(value, value) u1 (...); )
```

But, I am further confused by the `blink_leds` example [here](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=34391) that prepends the `#` token before the parameter list - in a top module!:

```
module blink_leds 
#(
    // Clock frequency
    parameter real CLK_FREQ     = 50.0e6,

    // LED LSB blink period
    parameter real BLINK_PERIOD = 0.5
)
```

Why would one feel compelled to redefine parameters that could not have been defined to begin with? This, and the myterious `(2)` has me seeking advice here. Thanks.

Comment: The first link is a unofficial red-line draft revision of a section of the IEEE1800. I suggest reading the free official [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). The second link is unrelated to parameters.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, for the link to the official spec.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are confusing module definition with module instantiation, and the syntax related to the two. Your first two examples are module instantiations, ie putting down a D-flip-flop or module foo, and defining the parameters implicitly for that single instantiation. So, only the dff u4 will have its parameter set to 2 and only u1 (an instance of module foo) will have its params set to value and value. If I were to instantiate another dff or foo, it may or may not have the same parameters as u4 and u1. For example, say I have a dff module with 1 parameter:

```
dff #(2) u1 (...);
dff #(4) u2 (...);
```

I instantiated two dff's with different values for that parameter, but me changing the parameter to 2 in u1 and 4 in u2 only affect those instances, not eachother and not any other dff I might later declare.

In constrast, when declaring a module, ie defining what a foo is, this is when I use the syntax in your third example:

```
module foo #(parameter real x = 0.5, parameter real y = 50.7) (input wire a, output wire b ...);
```

Here, I am defining what parameters module foo has, in this case parameters x and y. The values I am providing are the default values for those parameters. So, if I instantiate foo somewhere and DONT redefine the parameters, they will take on those values:

```
foo u1(...); // -- Instance of foo with x = 0.5 (default) and y = 50.7 (default)
foo #(1, 0.2) u2(...); // -- Instance of foo with x = 1 and y = 0.2
foo #(0.2) u3(...); // -- Instance of foo with x = 0.2 and y = 50.7 (default)
foo #(,1.4) u4(...); // -- Instance of foo with x = 0.5 (default) and y = 1.4
```

As with the dff above, here I am instantiating foo a bunch of times (u1..u4), redefining what the parameter values are for that instance. I am not changing the definition of foo, only the parameter values for that specific instance. So, just because I redefine x in u2, it has no baring on parameter x in u1, u3 or u4.

Comment: So revised parameters go, in parentheses, between the # token and the instantiated module name. Got it. Thanks, Unn.

Comment: @user901750 Yep, parameters help define the module at elaboration, so each instance needs whatever parameters a module has declared to be defined at that time. So, a module declaration includes defaults for parameters if a module instantiation does not define them (as in my example with u1, u3 and u4). As you care about SystemVerilog, you can better define parameters of instantiated modules with .name: `foo #(.x(1), .y(0.2)) u2(...);` That way, just as with ports, you dont have to worry about mixing up the order.